# Eliminating data points where the "Y" value is missing or NAN

Tags: python, arrays, database, nan

```
# Python code to demonstrate SQL to fetch data.

# importing the module
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import chisquare

# connect withe the myTable database
connection = sqlite3.connect(r"C:\Users\Aidan\Desktop\INA_DB.db")

# cursor object
crsr = connection.cursor()


dog= crsr.execute("Select s, ei, ki FROM INa_VC WHERE s IN ('d') ")
ans= crsr.fetchall() 

#x = [0]*len(ans); y = [0]*len(ans)
x= np.zeros(len(ans)); y= np.zeros(len(ans))

for i in range(0,len(ans)):
    x[i] = float(ans[i][1])
    y[i] = float(ans[i][2])


# Reshaping
x, y = x.reshape(-1,1), y.reshape(-1, 1)

# Linear Regression Object 
lin_regression = LinearRegression()

# Fitting linear model to the data
lin_regression.fit(x,y)

# Get slope of fitted line
m = lin_regression.coef_

# Get y-Intercept of the Line
b = lin_regression.intercept_

# Get Predictions for original x values
# you can also get predictions for new data
predictions = lin_regression.predict(x)
chi= chisquare(predictions, y)

# following slope intercept form 
print ("formula: y = {0}x + {1}".format(m, b)) 
print(chi)


plt.scatter(x, y,  color='black')
plt.plot(x, predictions, color='blue',linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

> Error:
>
> runfile('C:/Users/Aidan/.spyder-py3/temp.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/Aidan/.spyder-py3')
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> runfile('C:/Users/Aidan/.spyder-py3/temp.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/Aidan/.spyder-py3')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Aidan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 705, in runfile
>
> execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Aidan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>
> exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Aidan/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 28, in
>
> y[i] = float(ans[i][2])
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

The issue that I am 99 percent sure of is an issue with the Y value. For my data set I have some y values purposely missing and this is leading to a float error. Given my current script what would be a quick fix in order to filter OUT missing NAN y values?

This script works perfectly if y values are in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best answer is storing those values as the string `"nan"` in your db, which `float` parses just fine. Afterwards you can use for example [`np.isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) to get those values that are not defined.

As an alternative, leave them at zero:

```
for i in range(0, len(ans)):
    try:
        x[i] = float(ans[i][1])
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        y[i] = float(ans[i][2])
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Or, leave them out entirely:

```
xy = np.array([tuple(map(float, values[1:])) for values in ans if values[2]])
x = xy[:, 0]
y = xy[:, 1]
```

Comment: Ok that gave me an output on a graph

Comment: But i am receiving this: formula: y = [[-0.05226702]]x + [-2.84194874]
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=array([inf]), pvalue=array([0.]))
C:\Users\Aidan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py:4567: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  terms = (f_obs - f_exp)**2 / f_exp

Comment: @AidanDarragh: Well, now some of your y-values are zero, which might not make sense for the rest of your program (`f_exp` gets the value of `y`). So maybe you want to start with an array of ones, instead?

Comment: let me try the first method might be easier

Comment: coudl I do something like this in my oirignal script?:            filtered_data = raw_data[~np.isnan(raw_data["y"])]

Comment: @AidanDarragh: Yes but it would probably need to be `mask = ~np.isnan(y); y = y[mask]; x = x[mask]`, because you also want to filter out the x-values which correspond to the unset y-values.

Comment: would I just add that to my script? I'm trying to completely remove the row of data points with missing values not set them to zero and loop to the next

Comment: What should I add or remove to make the : mask = ~np.isnan(y); y = y[mask]; x = x[mask]     work??

Comment: @AidanDarragh: In that case either use my third option (which assumes that empty values occur only in the y-coordinate and are designated by an empty string `""`), or use what I commented above with the first option (empty values are designated by the string `"nan"` and can occur anywhere).